# XMPP traffic logging (ejabberd 13.12)

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

It seems that [mod_logxml](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_logxml) module is not compatible with ejabberd 13.12 version. Ejabberd fails to start when this module is installed.

My question is - is there another way how to log (file, database, etc) all the XMPP packets send and received by ejabberd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed mod_logxml.erl that it will work with eJabberd 13.12. You have to put in

> ejabberd/src/

Configs are for ejabberd.yml format:

`mod_logxml:
    stanza: [message, other]
    direction: [external]
    orientation: [send, recv]
    logdir: "/var/jabber/logs/"
    timezone: universal
    rotate_days: 1
    rotate_megs: 100
    rotate_kpackets: no
    check_rotate_kpackets: 1`

[Repository](https://github.com/kmaxat/mod_logxml)

Comment: I've forgot to uncomment "Proc !" line in receive_packet. I've edited the repo.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can make your own log module if you cannot find anything that fits your needs.

You can use a module I developed as a reference. This module which would intercept stanza with the type "chat" or "groupchat" and send a acknowledgement back to the sender.

You can modify this module by removing the type so it intercepts all stanza types and log whatever you want into a DB instead of sending a message back to the sender.

https://github.com/Mingism/ejabberd-stanza-ack